# Make countdown timer start after link is clicked

Tags: html

How can i Make countdown timer for my site links after a user clicked a link countdown timer should start. For example I have link "Link 1". I want when a user clicks on "Link 1" countdown timer starts. Can i Make countdown timer for all links?

Comment: use ajax...............

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
setTimeout( function ( ) { alert( "hi" ); }, 3000 );
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="setTimeout(); return false;">Hi in 3 seconds</a>
```

Comment: Hi
thanks for your answer. I would like display countdown timer opposite of link.
For example: when a user clicks Link this Timer "01:59:59" appear opposie of link

Comment: Like this: 11 Hours, 25 Minutes, 47 Seconds.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/